# Comparing between orthogonal BPSK and differential BPSK

Tags: communication, digital-communications, bpsk

Suppose two modulation schemes, orthogonal BPSK and differential BPSK.

In orthogonal BPSK, we transmit
$$\textbf{x}_{A}:= [x[0], x[1]]^{T}=[1, 0]^{T},$$ and
$$\textbf{x}_{B}:= [0, 1]^{T}.$$
This scheme conveys one bit of information and uses one real dimension per two symbol times.

On the other hand, in differential BPSK, we transmit
$$x[m]=u[m]x[m-1]$$
where the information symbol $$u[m] = \pm 1.$$
This scheme conveys one bit of information and uses one real dimension per one symbol time.

Above is the description in the textbook, but I cannot understand this straightforward.
In my opinion, in differential BPSK, when receiving a symbol, we should exploit the information symbol received in the previous symbol time, m-1. In this way, I think that it can be considered as exploiting two symbol times.

Which point I am misunderstanding is? Can you explain briefly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not really exploit two symbols.

It simply means the encoding difference, as either the currrent bit is same as the previous, or then it is different.

The encoded bits simply tell if the currect state must be flipped or not to reach the next state.

So in that sense you need the state of all previous bits, but usually a synchronization is assumed for a data stream or burst so you can start off with known state.

But all there is needed is for the receiver to remember current state, and one symbol of the transmitter can then toggle the receiver state or keep it, so one symbol is still one bit.

Comment: I understood. Thank you for your help.